# Read luks lvm volume from Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, lvm, luks

I have a pendrive with the ubuntu root partition encrypted with LUKS, and it's inside a lvm volume. How could I read the data from Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

#### How could I read the data from Windows 10?

You could try LibreCrypt:

> Features
>
> - Full transparent encryption, containers appear as removable disks in Windows Explorer.
> - Compatible with Linux encryption: dm-crypt and LUKS. Linux shell scripts support deniable encryption on Linux.
>
> Source [t-d-k/LibreCrypt: LibreCrypt: Transparent on-the-fly disk
>   encryption for Windows. LUKS
>   compatible.](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt)